# What TV shows would be best for improving English?

Tags: spoken-english, learning

English is my second language. I can speak,read,write English without any problem. But I am trying to find ways to level up my spoken English. I was wondering if someone can suggest a few tv shows or debates or something I can find on Internet (free of cost) that can help me further improve my English.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something beyond typical conversations? Is it public speaking you are looking for? I'm a bit curious since it seems like speaking is not a problem for you, and yet you didn't say anything about your listening skill level. If you have a strong listening skill, then virtually all the videos on YouTube can be your resource.

Comment: Yes speaking is not problem for me. I am not as fluent in English as I am in my mother tongue. But I want to. 
I can debate better in my mother tongue than in English. So yes I am looking for beyond typical conversation which we find in tv series and movies.

Comment: I would say it depends on your taste. If you want to counter arguments during the conversation, then most of TV series could serve you quite well. (I watched things like *Simpsons*, *Fringe*, *CSI*, besides movies and news on my cable. I also enjoy watching video clips on YouTube too.) For public speaking, there are several good ones on the web (for examples, Steve Jobs). I don't know if you want to sound like a politician, but politician's speech is one of the greatest examples of public speaking, imho.

Comment: I did think of watching politician's speech but then I then I thought it might be just too boring. But I will give it a try.

Comment: Before making this question sounds too much like a chat, I will just make my last recommendations here on some political talks that aren't boring. If you can find the movie *Inside Job*, I recommend you to try it. You will find a more than decent narration and loads of witty speeches. (If not, you can still find some clips of it on YouTube.) For political speeches, try searching for "C-SPAN", and you will get the real stuff.

Comment: I see that my question has been put on hold as primarily opinion-based.. I understand that this is not a discussion forum but  I believe that as the name `English Language Learners` suggests, this question is fairly valid. How else would someone ask for resources? We have `English Language and Usage` for questions regarding English grammar and usage  etc

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this can vary dramatically based on what form of english you are trying to improve: conversational, educational, political, etc...

Generally, news broadcasts have wide varieties of speech that would be useful and would run the whole gamut.

Many educational youtube 'shows' might also be helpful.  Perhaps the various [Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/user/crashcourse) series on youtube would be helpful.  Much of what is said is in a more conversational tone but due to the educational nature you'd get some decent variety (and you'd be able to learn some cool stuff at the same time).

If all you're looking for is general conversational english, sitcoms might be your best bet.  I know several people who actually learned much of their conversational english from shows like [Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends), which I'm sure you can probably find online.

That said, there is no real 'wrong answer' - though I'd avoid very localized tv shows (such as the recently popular 'reality tv' programs following southern crocodile hunters, fishers, moonshiners, etc) and shows which take place in the distant past which may use outdated language uncommon today.

Comment: Most of the crash course teach you basic grammar. (well that's what I think, I haven't undertaken any course as such.) 
And yes sitcom shows like Friends and Seinfeld did help me a lot improving my conversational skills. Thank You. +1

Answer (score 1):

When I was taking a Legal Writing class towards a Paralegal degree our attorney instructor always recommended the classic sitcom Frasier to help build vocabulary and general use of high level English. The dialogue is expansive and rich, infused with lots of "GRE" words as many call them these days.

Comment: I havent watched Frasier not yet. Since you said that your attorney instructor recommended it to help build vocabulary I think I will give it a try. Thanks +1